# 'float' object is not callable while creating dictionary from Enum in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, enums

I've created an Enum in Python 3.4 with some data and a function that returns an ffactor based on the enumeration. I would like to make a dictionary of the ffactors from each Enum. So I tried this:

```
class RaceType(Enum):
    GS = 0 
    SC = 1 
    CL = 2 
    @property
    def ffactor(self):
        if self is RaceType.GS:
            return 660.0
        if self is RaceType.SC or self is RaceType.CL:
            return 500.0

zeroes = {this: this.ffactor() for this in RaceType}
```

However, this threw an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse.py", line 28, in <module>
    zeroes = {this: this.ffactor() for this in RaceType}
  File "parse.py", line 28, in <dictcomp>
    zeroes = {this: this.ffactor() for this in RaceType}
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

I tried manually writing out what I want and still got the same error:

```
zeroes = {RaceType.GS: RaceType.GS.ffactor(),
          RaceType.SC: RaceType.SC.ffactor(),
          RaceType.CL: RaceType.CL.ffactor()}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You defined `ffactor` as a `@property`, which means that it acts like an attribute not a method.

```
In [4]: zeroes = {this: this.ffactor for this in RaceType}

In [5]: zeroes
Out[5]: {<RaceType.SC: 1>: 500.0,
         <RaceType.GS: 0>: 660.0,
         <RaceType.CL: 2>: 500.0}
```

Comment: Both these are correct, and you both answered at nearly the same time! I wish I could give two accepted answers!

Comment: @smpl feel free to accept the other answer too! :P. Bah or don't since vaultah deleted :P